# GAE deployment error: "Cannot write multiple packages"

Tags: google-app-engine, build

Upon moving my projects files to a new computer, I can no longer deploy to Google App Engine. I don't know how to deciper the error, and my Google searches turn up nothing. Here is what gets returned:

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                           
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ca8b6f48-9892-449a-a6d8-b220182e8d7c status: FAILURE
Error ID: 4daa946e
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: go build: cannot write multiple packages to non-directory /layers/google.go.build/bin/main
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/[build log address]
```

The project builds fine on my local machine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: go114 
instance_class: F1 
env_variables: 
BUCKET_NAME: "****.appspot.com" 
handlers: 
- url: /robots.txt 
  static_files: robots.txt 
  upload: robots.txt 
- url: /styles 
  static_dir: styles 
  secure: always 
- url: /scripts 
  static_dir: scripts 
  secure: always 
- url: /.* 
  script: auto 
  secure: always
```

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: You are deploying with cloud build? Can you provide dockerfile and app.yaml?

Comment: I'm not using a dockerfile, just the plain vanilla GAE. The app.yaml looks like this:

runtime: go114

instance_class: F1

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "****.appspot.com"

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles
  secure: always
  
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

Comment: Still it will be hard to find the reason, you can get more information when you deploy with command `gcloud app deploy --verbosity="debug"`